# In EmEditor, how can I delete all rows that contain a given search pattern?

Tags: emeditor

Search pattern \t[a-z] with Match Case open activated, highlights a few rows in a *.csv file (see screenshot). Is there a way to delete all these rows with one click in EmEditor?

[Screenshot shows a couple of rows that contain search pattern: tab followed by lower case letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia2Mh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete filtered lines *while being filtered*.
You can record these keyboard steps to a macro. A recorded **JavaScript for EmEditor** macro will look like this. This macro will also abort the **Filter** after deleting lines:

```
document.selection.SelectAll();
document.selection.Delete(1);
document.Filter("",0,0,0,0,0);
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `Macro.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run Macro.jsee** in the **Macros** menu while filtered.

Comment: For the record, I had to upgrade to the professional version of EmEditor to see the filter ribbon.